# Endless Loop Happens when Displaying 3 Dots Loading Animation

Tags: c#, .net-5

I just asked something similar before, but now, I tried to do this on my own with, but it seems to not being working as I specified. I've written a method which prints a Loading Animation on a Console Application (the 3 Dots that appear and disappear) and I've decided to implement it on my program I'm working for.

What I need to do is to print the Loading Animation until a Process is Finished, and I saw some methods that Initializes a new Thread (which can't be used with my methods because, ThreadStart needs a Void with no Parameters to work properly). Other methods, just display the Loading Animations until the User Press any Key (Console.ReadLine() Method) and that is not what I'm desired to do.

My own Code is similar from the Ones from Internet I saw, but I made some changes, first: it Displays the Loader Animation along with the String I'm desired to Print onscreen, and second: it does not Initializes a Thread, because, when I start a Thread it cannot be Cancelled with Thread.Abort().

If the Loader Animation is Printed, then, it'll never end, and the Loop will never break, Forcing the Program to Stop working.

Here's my Code I wrote, any help or Advice is very Appreciated:

I. Three Loading Dots Method:

```
public static void Display_Loading_Dots(string String_to_Print, bool Action_is_Done)
{

while(Action_is_Done == false) // If Action is not Done, Process Display the Loading Animation it Until it is
{
Console.Write("{0}", String_to_Print);

char Dot = '.';
int Interval = 1000;

for(int Index = 0; Index < 3; Index++)
{
Console.Write(Dot);
Thread.Sleep(Interval);     

if(Index == 2)
{
Console.Write("\b\b\b   \b\b\b");
Index = -1;

Thread.Sleep(Interval);
}

}

}

if(Action_is_Done == true) // If the Action is Done, Stop Displaying the Dots
{
// This is Supposed to Break the for Block from the if Block, which is the One that Displays the Loading Animation
}

}

}

}
```

II. An Example where I'm trying to Stop the Three Dots Animation, but it doesn't:

```
string String_to_Print = "\nOpening the File \"" + Input_File_Name + "\"";

bool Action_is_Done = false;

// Let's Suppose, We just Opened the File and the Action its Done, so now, we have to Stop Displaying the Loading Animation

Process_Action(Action_String, Action_is_Done);
Action_is_Done = true; // Change the Boolean, to true, so the Loop will be Breaked

Process_Action(Action_String, Action_is_Done); // Does nothing, the Loop is not being Broken as Specified
```

Comment: You are not setting `Action_is_Done` to `true` anywhere in `while` loop

Comment: So what I need to do is to invert the Booleans?
Action_is_Done for while to true and for if false?

Comment: you need to set it `true` to come out of loop

Comment: The `Actin_is_Done` variable in your first snippet is local to the function (because it's a parameter). So even if you change the variable that was used to pass this parameter, that won't change `Action_is_done` within the function, thus your loop condition never invalidates

Comment: What should I do on this case then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest getting the code that writes the dots out of your normal flow

```
    var x = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
    var writeDotsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
              //TODO: Write your dots
    }, x.Token);

    //TODO: Load your stuff
    x.Cancel();
```

or even invert the logic, which i personally prefer

```
    var doLoadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
        //TODO: Load your stuff      
    });

    int approprateMillisecondWaitBetweenDotsDrawing = 500;
    while(!doLoadTask.IsCompleted){
           //TODO: Write your dots
           Task.Delay(approprateMillisecondWaitBetweenDotsDrawing).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, there @T.Nielsen, I'm going to use your method but first, I have some questions for you, so like that, I can figure out how:

A) Inside the StartNew Block for the Task, does the Stuff to be Loaded refers to the String to be Printed or the Action to be Called?

B) How can I make it Stop once I've done with an Action, should I use a Bool as a Parameter like I did on my method or what do you suggest for that?

Comment: Hi @APersonfromtheUniverse if i understand your question correctly a) load stuff was referring to the action to be called, that which takes time, i presumed you were loading something, but it could be any lengthy operation  that you would show dots while happening. b) so in the first example you print your dots in the worker thread and cancel it when loading completes => stop, in the second you work in the work thread and it exits/ completes when done to exit your loop. Keep in mind .IsCompleted is not the same as .IsCompletedSuccessfully, so have to also check for success.

Comment: Well, that's what I've done, is it correct?

Code Segment A:

`public static void Process_Action(string Action_String, bool Action_is_Done)
{
CancellationTokenSource Action_Stopper_Source = new CancellationTokenSource();
Action Action = () => { Console.Write("{0}", Action_String); };

CancellationToken Action_Stopper = Action_Stopper_Source.Token;
var Display_Action = Task.Factory.StartNew(Action, Action_Stopper); // Load the Action and Display it before Processing it 

char Dot = '.';
int Interval = 500;`

Comment: Code Segment B:

`if(Action_is_Done == false) // If the Action is not Done, Process it Until it is
{
// Empty Conditional Block. This Doesn't Stop the Action Processor Until the Action its Done
}

else // If the Action is Done, Abort it
{
Action_Stopper_Source.Cancel();
}`

Comment: Code Segment C (the Last one): `while(!Display_Action.IsCompleted) // As the Action is not Done yet, Keep Processing it Until it is
{
Task Process = Task.Delay(Interval);

for(int Index = 0; Index < 3; Index++)
{
Console.Write(Dot);

TaskAwaiter Task_Awaiter = Process.GetAwaiter(); // Suspend the Task
Task_Awaiter.GetResult(); // Continue with the Task

if(Index == 2)
{
Console.Write("\b\b\b   \b\b\b");
Index = -1;

Task_Awaiter = Process.GetAwaiter(); // Suspend the Task
Task_Awaiter.GetResult(); // Continue with the Task
}

}

}

}`

Comment: What I'm doing with the Task Display_Action is to Print a String (Action_String is the Parameter for it) that indicates the User what's going on (like Opening File + Dots Animation, Closing File + Dots Animation, Reading File + Dots Animation) and after the File is Opened or Closed (whatever that needs to be Done), then it Stop displaying that Loading Animation.

The Parameter Action_Is_Done is a Boolean used to Stop it once the Action/Function I called on my Main Program is Completed or Succesfully Completed.